# HTML form action and jsp issues

Tags: jsp

this is first file--->one.jsp

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form action="two.jsp" method="post">
 <input type="button" value="ok"/>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

next file--->two.jsp

```
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 hehehehe
 </body>
 </html>
```

the response is nothing when click that button. there is something wrong with my eclipse?whatever i create the new project i cant access this form action. but form action working my previous projects.please some one help me with this basic.thx in advance.

Comment: check your question ,it make no sense

Answer (score 0):

You need a submit button not a regular button

```
<input type="submit" value="ok"/>
```